# PHP SESSION data lost between page loads with WAMPserver 2.0 on localhost

Tags: php, session, authentication, wampserver

I have a PHP authentication system on my website using the $_SESSION variable.

A form submits a username and password to the file "login.php". It is handled like this:

```
<?php include '../includes/sessionstart.inc.php'; ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>

if($_POST){
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT id, company FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q) >= 1){
        $f = mysql_fetch_Array($q);
        $_SESSION['company'] = $f['company'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $f['id'];
        $_SESSION['logedin'] = true;
        session_write_close();

        ob_clean();
        header("Location: index.php");

}
```

Afterwards, index.php is loaded and checks whether 'logedin' is true.

```
<?php include '../includes/sessionstart.inc.php'; ?>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'])) header('Location: login.php'); ?>
```

On my production server, it continues, but on my Wampserver, it reverts back to login.php. I notice that Wampserver is very slow in page loading, this might have to do something with it. That's why I included the session_write_close, to make sure session data is saved before the pages are switched, but it doesn't help.

The contents of session_start.inc.php are simply:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

I used to have more code in there, but at the moment it's just this. The problem also existed before I started using an include file.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't Wampserver transmit my SESSION data to the next PHP file?

Comment: Have you checked the headers coming from your server, that they actually include the session cookie?

Comment: When I do a print_r($_SESSION), nothing displays. How can I check the raw headers?

Comment: You can do it with the Firefox extensions Firebug or Live http headers, or use a network sniffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I have fixed this bug finally.

On my localhost WAMP, the session data is not saved between page loads, because the session data is stored in a cookie, and there is no cookie domain to be set for localhost.

The solution:

> 'session.cookie_domain' should be set to empty string for all local domain names, not only for 'localhost' (but should not be empty for local IP addresses):

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.') !== false) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '');
?>
```

Thanks to Marcin Wiazowski [who posted it here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#74231).

Answer (score 6):

WAMP server 2  - settings are not set by default for `$_SESSION` var.

**PHP.ini** 
requires the following settings

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini
session.cookie_domain =
session.use_cookies = 1
session.save_path = "c:\wamp\tmp"   ;ensure the \ is used not /
```

---

**Session testing -** 
load.php -- load `$_SESSION` var.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = 'stored variable';
session_write_close();
header("location:print.php");
?>
```

print.php -- print $_SESSION var.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

run the script in your browser `var_dump()` should produce results

go to `c:\wamp\tmp` Files containing the session data will appear here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: the index `logedin` seems strange for keeping track of a user being logged in. Is this just a typo on SO, or really a code-typo?

Second (depending on the desired behavior), try another approach for making pages login-protected. Your page should look something like

```
<?php
  include 'login.inc.php';

  if(authorized()) {
    // put some more script here, if needed
    ?>
    // put some plain HTML here  
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Where `login.inc.php` handles the session, cookies. In particular, the `authorized` function should return TRUE if a client is already logged in. If a client is not logged in, it should display a form with action `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and return FALSE. If you name the submit-input something like `login_submit`, you can let `login.inc.php` handle the verification.

This way, you don't need to refer users to a dedicated login page, and after logging in, user are directly shown the requested page. You can tweak this a bit to make query-strings persistent through login as well.

Comment: The 'logedin' is an inherited typo from the previous developer working on this project.

Comment: Thanks.. I implemented your approach, the code is much more tidy now and the login falls through to the actual page instead of doing the redirect. Although I'm still not sure what caused the problem, I have a solution, and that's most important!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
if($_POST){...}
```

with

```
if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){...}
```

... at least for debugging purposes. It's possible that some different settings are causing a non-empty $_POST array where it's not expected.

Also, your code seems to be missing `exit()` calls after `header()` redirections. Sending an HTTP *Location* header doesn't automatically stop your script.

Comment: thanks.. i was already busy implementing Martijn's approach, stumbled upon the if($POST){...} line and corrected it myself. Nice that you also mention it. I'll also check for missing exit calls.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using WAMPSERVER for development on /localhost. I needed to change `session.use_only_cookies` either in-line or in the `php.ini` setting from

```
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

to

```
session.use_only_cookies = 0
```

***Explanation***

Using default cookie-based sessions was working as expected but I needed a cookie-less solution. A test starting page:

```
<?php
// page1.php

ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
session_start();

$_SESSION['time'] = time();

echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

The session data was created and stored successfully in the WAMPSERVER temp directory, e.g., `C:\wamp\tmp\sess_0rkdlonl5uia717rf03d4svs16`. The link generated by the above code looks similar to (note the UID matches the session data file name):

`page2.php?PHPSESSID=0rkdlonl5uia717rf03d4svs16`

But the destination page2.php was throwing undefined errors for the variable 'time' whilst attempting to retrieve the session data:

```
<?php
// page2.php

ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
session_start();

echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

echo '<br /><a href="page1.php?' . SID . '">page 1</a>';
?>
```

By setting `session.use_only_cookies` FALSE in either the script before `session_start();`:

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '0');
```

or changing it globally in `php.ini`:

```
; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combatting
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the end all be all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies = 0
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem but it was being caused by

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

So I just deleted it from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Update to WAMP 2.5 and now the problem is solved!