# Session variable not staying set

Tags: php, session

**Warning:** Not a duplicate, I can't find this problem.

I'm testing and building my website on localhost. I have the following code on my login page, sending the user to their profile page if they have a user ID cookie, and their IP is the same as their cookies says it should be.

```
if($_COOKIE["IPcookie"] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    $cookieresult = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS count FROM users WHERE username="$_COOKIE["usercookie"]" AND `active`="1"');
    if($cookieresult == 0) {
        $loginquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=" .$_COOKIE['usercookie']);
        $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginquery);
        $dbIDlogin = $row5['ID']; 
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $dbIDlogin;
        header('Location: /userprofile.php');
    }
```

However, when I go to the user profile using these cookies, `$_SESSION['userID']` is sometimes `NULL`. I can't seem to figure out why "sometimes" the `$_SESSION` goes `NULL`. I can't seem to find any pattern in it. I login one user, click to all the links on their profile page that go to different areas of the website and then go back to `loginuser.php`(the file shown above), and it works with one user, but doesn't with another. It seems to be completely random, which confuses me. I can't think of any reason it would change inbetween users. I'll continue to test this, and see if I can find a pattern, but with several hours put in already, it appears completely random.

My problem does not appear to be answered by any of these:

[PHP SESSION data lost between page loads with WAMPserver 2.0 on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153465/php-session-data-lost-between-page-loads-with-wampserver-2-0-on-localhost)
-I checked my php.ini, it has those lines of code (though a different, but functioning tmp file). The example code in the selected answer testing the $_SESSION variable works like a charm. My code, doesn't.

[PHP Session not Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976930/php-session-not-saving)
My `session_save_path()` is writable.

[PHP session not being saved between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584121/php-session-not-being-saved-between-pages)
[PHP Session data not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)
I'm on localhost, not a server.

`session_start();` is on EVERY page, excluding templates that are only referenced in pages that have `session_start();` at the beginning (because if `session_start();` is in the template then it comes up with an error about how the session is already started).

**UPDATE:** I may have a pattern. Users with usernames including letters do not have their information saved. All of these users also have longer usernames, as their usernames are words like "dummy" and "eport" as opposed to "1" and "9." It works for 1 and 9, but not for dummy and eport. Now, this makes no sense, as they are all identified by their ID's which are always numbers, but this does appear to be a pattern.

Update(the relevant code from userprofile.php):

```
<?php

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
var_dump($_SESSION['userID']);


//get.
$totalquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='$userID'");
$arrayquery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalquery);
$username = $arrayquery['username'];

//Firstname
$firstname = $arrayquery['firstname'];
echo 'Welcome ' .  $firstname;
//Lastname

?>
```

Comment: Did you include `session_start();` anywhere? If not, **it will fail**. Consult => http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php *"I don't see it in your code, nor is it mentioned."*

Comment: @Fred I have `session_start();` in the beginning of every php file. It wouldn't even work sometimes if that wasn't there. Sorry for not including that in my question, it is the answer to most of these problems. I've updated it now.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. Yours sounds like a very particular problem. I doubt I can be of further help.

Comment: The fact that integer usernames are working and that the variables are called by their IDs leads me to believe something is getting mixed up there...maybe you have a line of code with calls the username instead of the ID, but it works sometimes because the name is an ID. But this problem will be hard to solve given our limited information.

Comment: I'll add the code from the user profile that should be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit of code basically does nothing:

```
$cookieresult = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS count FROM users WHERE username="$_COOKIE["usercookie"]" AND `active`="1"');
```

As $cookieresult well only loosely equal `0` (it will actually be `false`) when the query actually fails.  I am guessing the what you really need to do is to actually read the data out of the result resource handle that gets set to `$cookieresult` to determine your value for `count(ID)`.

Comment: I understand the idea of what you're saying, but I'm still confused. That code does nothing, I can't figure out what I was trying to do with that... and it's making less sense the more I look at it.

I changed it to:
`$cookieresult = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="$_COOKIE["usercookie"]" AND `active`="1"');`
and it still works, the header still activates. But, since that exists, shouldn't it be positive or 1? Why does it activate when it shouldn't? Can you explain more, or explain how to "read the data out of the result?"

Comment: Sounds like you got things working.  The main thing I was gettign at is that you didn't call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or similar to actually read the data out of the result set pointer that was returned from `mysqli_query()`.  One other thing I should have noted is that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You need to either escape your cookie variable before using it in the queries, or better yet you could investigate the use of parametrized prepared statements, which is REALLY what you should be learning if you plan to work with DB's extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in code, if anyone needs it in the future, or was interested. I'm not sure what all of the code was doing in the original, looking back, I probably should study more SQL syntax. Thanks for the help, Mike.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["usercookie"])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE["IPcookie"])) {
        echo('Cookie detected, processing, wait a second.');
        if($_COOKIE["IPcookie"] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
            $cookieusername = $_COOKIE["usercookie"];
            $cookieresult = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$cookieusername' AND active=1");

            if(!$cookieresult or mysqli_num_rows($cookieresult) == 0) {
                echo('We really don\'t believe your cookie is real, sorry.');           
            }
            else {
                $loginquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$cookieusername'");
                $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginquery);
                $dbIDlogin = $row5['ID']; 
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $dbIDlogin;
                session_write_close();
                header('Location: /userprofile.php');
            }   
        }   
        else {
            echo('We don\'t currently believe your cookie is real, sorry.');

        }
    }
    else {
        echo('We don\'t believe your cookie is real, sorry.');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if enter into if-statement or not.
If not please check if "output_buffering" from php.ini set "ON"

Comment: The answer above is my answer, I already found the solution. Thanks though!