# Custom Identity loses session information

Tags: php, session, authentication, yii, yii2

For some reason, after logging in, the user details gets lost.

I created a `Customer` class, implemented `IdentityInterface` and extended `ActiveRecord` with this class.

When a customer logs in, the customer is properly authenticated. I noticed at this point (using a var_dump) that the `Yii::$app->user` is properly set to the appropriate `Customer` instance, and I also noticed the `Yii::$app->session` is enabled. This is right after the `$model->login()` function; where `$model` here is an instance of the de-facto `LoginForm` below.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getCustomer(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, after the redirect in `$this->goBack()`, I noticed `Yii::$app->user` — which was once an instance of `yii\web\User`, with its identityClass at `app/models/Customer` — is now `null`. I also noticed that the session at this point (immediately after the redirect) is `null`.

This means `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` is always `true` even after a customer has been properly authenticated.

How do I carry the logged-in user along through the redirect?

Comment: show code from user model and actionLogin

Comment: It could be a server setting, killing your session.

Comment: @ineersa I've added the `login` function

Comment: @JelledeFries what server setting on a local installation of WAMP could be responsible?

Comment: @JelledeFries I already saw that; & I am already extending ActiveRecord and implementing IdentityInterface

Comment: @Yasky yeah, I reread your post and removed my comment.

Comment: @Yasky you can check if it is a server setting by trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13626184/980615

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76548/discussion-between-yasky-and-jelle-de-fries).

Comment: Best way to solve this problem is to use `git bisect` with a good test. Else, start from a clean slate; hopfully you don't encounter this problem too late into development

Comment: You finally realized what is the problem? I have the same issue here.